SPL_TOKEN_2022 INITIALIZE GROUP - "Invalid instruction"
I am trying to create collection with spl-token-2022 using token-group.
But when initialze group, there appears error.
    'Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb invoke [2]',
    'Program log: Error: Invalid instruction',
    'Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb consumed 833 of 142231 compute units',
    'Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb failed: custom program error: 0xc',

This is source code.
    let init_group_ix = &spl_token_group_interface::instruction::initialize_group(
        &spl_token_2022::id(),
        ctx.accounts.mint.key,
        ctx.accounts.mint.key,
        ctx.accounts.nft_authority.to_account_info().key,
        Some(*ctx.accounts.nft_authority.to_account_info().key),
        100,
    );

    invoke_signed(
        init_group_ix,
        &[
            ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info().clone(),
            ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info().clone(),
            ctx.accounts.nft_authority.to_account_info().clone(),
            ctx.accounts.nft_authority.to_account_info().clone(),
        ],
        signer,
    )?;

If anyone knows anything about this issue, I would really appreciate it if you could let me know.

The token-group extension hasn't been released yet on all networks, but it will be very soon!
